# PID control causes motor to make a droning sound

Tags: arduino, dc-motor, pid-controller, kalman-filter

I have a PID program that sends my linear actuator with potentiometer feedback to roughly the same position within 0.05 inches accuracy as the result of several measurements I've taken.

When it reaches the target position it makes a droning sound that comes from the motor getting small inputs from the PID function.

Here is the graph of the result. https://imgur.io/a/9qZsM2N

- Does this damage the motor?
- What is the best way to get rid of this droning sound?
- Should I have it time out?
- Is my PID incorrectly tuned?

```
#include <PID_v1.h>
#include "CytronMotorDriver.h"
#include <SimpleKalmanFilter.h>

double Input, Output; // ,Setpoint
double Setpoint = 88; 

// Specify the links and initial tuning parameters
double Kp = 48, Ki = .1, Kd = 17.6;

PID myPID(&Input, &Output, &Setpoint, Kp, Ki, Kd, DIRECT);
SimpleKalmanFilter simpleKalmanFilter(2.0f, 2.0f, 0.01f);
CytronMD motor(PWM_DIR, 9, 8);  
    
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  myPID.SetSampleTime(200);
  myPID.SetOutputLimits(-255, 255);
  myPID.SetMode(AUTOMATIC);
}
    
void loop() {
  Input = simpleKalmanFilter.updateEstimate(analogRead(A0));
  myPID.Compute();
  Serial.println(Output);
    
  motor.setSpeed(Output);
      
  Serial.print("analog value on Pot:");
  Serial.print(analogRead(A0));
  Serial.print("input:");
  Serial.print(Input);
  Serial.print(",");
  Serial.print("output:");
  Serial.print(Output);
  Serial.print('\n');
}
```

Comment: You need to measure the output and put it in a graph so you have an idea of that the PID is resulting in. Maybe the P is oscillating for example. Without measurements it's all guessing.

Comment: You can add a dead-band to 0.03 inches for example, so the motor stops when the position is within 0.03 inches of the target.

Comment: How do I add the picture of the graph? It says it is forbidden

Comment: @belza00 If you use the insert image button in the editor, it'll show a link until someone with enough rep enables it to appear directly in the post.

Comment: Either your PID parameters need some trimming or your input signal is a bit noisy. The digital filter might not make it alone or also needs more tuning. Log the PID input values - how stable are they for a set position? What is the application? Does it sit longer times on a fixed position?

Comment: yes the application is that the actuator extends and moves a camera on a gimbal out of a certain location. I want it to be able to hold steady for long periods of time

Comment: @Lundin i added the graph. It looks  it comes pretty close to stable but still not close enough to stop the buzzing

Comment: Even high quality professionally designed servos do this unless you add some deadband.